# Insertar variables PHP en SQL a mi base de datos

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Tengo un problema con crear un registro de usuario, lo que trato de hace es que desde los inputs que cree en html se almacene la información en php cree la variable con la información obtenida del input y utilizar esa variable para crear un nuevo usuario en mi Base de Datos con SQL (ya saben lo típico).

Pero al momento de hacer el registro de dice este error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null on line 15.
```

Ya verifique pero parece que algo estoy haciendo mal espero haberles brindado todo la información necesaria a continuación el código:

```
<?php
session_start();
 
// Datos para conectar a la base de datos.
$nombreServidor = "*********";
$nombreUsuario = "******";
$passwordBaseDeDatos = "*********";
$nombreBaseDeDatos = "******";

// Crear conexión con la base de datos.
$conn = new mysqli($nombreServidor, $nombreUsuario, $passwordBaseDeDatos, $nombreBaseDeDatos);


// registrar usuario 
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (correo,password,nombre,apellido_p,apellido_m,colonia,calle,numero,CP,telefono) VALUES (:email,:contra,:nombre,:Apaterno,:Amaterno,:colonia,:calle,:numero,:CP,:tel)");
//$stmt->bind_param(array($email,$contra,$nombre,$Apaterno,$Amaterno,$colonia,$calle,$numero,$CP,$tel));

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':contra', $contra);
$stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
$stmt->bindParam(':Apaterno', $Apaterno);
$stmt->bindParam(':contra', $Amaterno);
$stmt->bindParam(':Amaterno', $colonia);
$stmt->bindParam(':calle', $calle);
$stmt->bindParam(':numero', $numero);
$stmt->bindParam(':CP', $CP);
$stmt->bindParam(':tel', $tel);



$email = $_POST['email'];
$contra = $_POST['psw'];
$nombre = $_POST['name'];
$Apaterno = $_POST['apaterno'];
$Amaterno = $_POST['amaterno'];
$colonia = $_POST['colonia'];
$calle = $_POST['calle'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$CP = $_POST['codigop'];
$tel = $_POST['telefono'];
$stmt->execute();




/*$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (correo,password,nombre,apellido_p,apellido_m,colonia,calle,numero,CP,telefono) VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$_POST[psw]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[apaterno]','$_POST[amaterno]','$_POST[colonia]','$_POST[calle]','$_POST[numero]','$_POST[codigop]','$_POST[telefono]')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
*/

?>
```

Comment: Tienes una mezcla de funciones y drivers, estás usando `bindParam` que es de PDO y lo tratas de trabajar sobre una conexión de mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás construyendo tu conexión a través de una instancia de [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php), entonces:

- Usar el método `bind_param` en lugar de `bindParam` que es de la clase PDO
- El método `bind_param` recibe

  - Un [string](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters) con los tipos de datos que espera en cada posición
  - Posterior podemos indicar separadas por coma `,` cada una de las variables
- Para el caso del método `prepare` haciendo uso de [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) usaremos como marcadores el símbolo de `?` en lugar del marcador de parámetros

Prueba tu código así:

```
<?php 

// Datos para conectar a la base de datos.
$passwordBaseDeDatos = "*********";
$nombreBaseDeDatos   = "******";
$nombreServidor      = "*********";
$nombreUsuario       = "******";

// Crear conexión con la base de datos.
$conn = new mysqli($nombreServidor, $nombreUsuario, $passwordBaseDeDatos, $nombreBaseDeDatos);

$Apaterno = $_POST['apaterno'];
$Amaterno = $_POST['amaterno'];
$colonia  = $_POST['colonia'];
$contra   = $_POST['psw'];
$nombre   = $_POST['name'];
$numero   = $_POST['numero'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$calle    = $_POST['calle'];
$tel      = $_POST['telefono'];
$CP       = $_POST['codigop'];

    
// registrar usuario 
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (
                                                    correo,
                                                    password,
                                                    nombre,
                                                    apellido_p,
                                                    apellido_m,
                                                    colonia,
                                                    calle,
                                                    numero,
                                                    CP,
                                                    telefono
                                                ) 
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    ")) {
    
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssssiis', $email, $contra, $nombre, $Apaterno, $Amaterno, $colonia, $calle, $numero, $CP, $tel);

    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    echo $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: me marca el siguiente error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /homepages/43/d841562397/htdocs/clickandbuilds/web/web/singup.php on line 39

Comment: asi es, ¿no tendrá que ver que tenga una id en mi base de datos o si?

Comment: perfecto deja lo pruebo

Comment: bro, me arroja ahora este problema **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in on line 25**  que es la parte del `if ($stmt = $con->prepare` ¿puede ser un problema externo a php ya sea que ingrese mal algo en mi html?

Comment: haha es verdad Bro, Gracias y si tienes un lugar donde pueda aprender mas de estas cosas me seria de mucha ayuda!.

Comment: La doc de PHP siempre es un excelente punto de partida, ayudándote de ella puedes resolver todas las dudas que tengas yo la tengo en favoritos, por otro lado trata de usar nombres más expresivos para las variables, por eso me perdí en $con